# How to use ring of for to put letters together to form a word?

Tags: c++, for-loop, sum, char, cin

As we can store and add numbers.

How to get the letters of a color in this code grain by grain and then display it in full, using `for`

For example:

```
enter n:4
number1:b
number2:l
number3:u
number4:e
color: blue
```

My problem is I don't know what to do to save all the letters, not just the last letter.

```
int n;
char a;
char sum=sum;
cout<<"enter n:";
cin>>n;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    cout<<"number"<<i<<":";
    cin>>a;
    sum=a;
}
cout<<"color: "<<sum;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `+` operator

```
int n;
char a;
string s="";
cout<<"enter n:";
cin>>n;
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    cout<<"number"<<i<<":";
    cin>>a;
    s += a;
}
cout<<"color: "<<s;
```

If you need individual letter, use string.at(postion) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = 0;
cin >> n; //number of chars in word
char* word = new char[n+1];

for( int i=0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> word[i];
}

word[n] = '\0';

cout<<"color: "<< word << endl;

delete [] word;
```